# Mi código no funciona pero tampoco muestra errores

Tags: arduino

estoy haciendo un oximetro que cuando registra que bajan las pulsaciones debe hacer sonar una bocina y prender un led, el codigo no me marca error al correrlo pero no hace lo que debería. la bocina se encuentran juntos en el puerto 13 del arduino.

```
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  int tiempo = 0;
  int tiempo2 = 0;
  float Arreglo1[20];
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(voltage);

  if (voltage <= 2.5) {
    if (voltage <= 2.5) {
      tiempo = millis();
      while (voltage <= 2.5) {
        tiempo2 = millis();
      }

      if (tiempo2 <= 60) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 5); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
        delay(1000); // wait for a second
      }
    } else {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 2.5); // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delay(1000); // wait for a second
    }

    tiempo = 0;
    tiempo2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //Guarden los valores del voltaje
      Arreglo1[i] = voltage;
      if (Arreglo1[i] > 0) {
        tiempo++; //COntador del pulso es igual a 1++
      }
      if (Arreglo1[i] == 0) {
        tiempo2++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (voltage <= 2.5) {
  if (voltage <= 2.5) {
    tiempo = millis();
    while (voltage <= 2.5) {
      tiempo2 = millis();
```

El segundo bucle te sobra, ya que si el primero se cumple es obvio que el segundo también.

Por otro lado, dado que la función `loop` se ejecuta una y otra vez, lo que consigues con el `while` es capturar la ejecución. Mientras el voltaje sea inferior a 2.5 la ejecución va a quedarse atascada en el `while` y no va a hacer otra cosa.

Para este caso quizás deberías usar una variable estática para almacenar los tiempos. Así dispones de una forma de almacenar los tiempos entre ejecuciones consecutivas de `loop`:

```
int tiempo1 = -1;
int tiempo2 = -1;

void loop()
{
  // ...

  if (voltage <= 2.5) {
    if (tiempo1 < 0)
      tiempo1 = millis();
    else
      tiempo2 = millis();

    if (tiempo2-tiempo1>=60) {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 5); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delay(1000); // wait for a second
      tiempo1=tiempo2;
   } 


  //...
} else {
  tiempo1 = -1;
  tiempo2 = -1;
}
```

De esta forma el programa no se queda atascado